# trying to do a bot merged in an app error about jakarta

Tags: java, android-studio

Iḿ doing a Telegram bot merged in an app to avoid connect application to a REST API or email (I find this so messy to do) telegram bot is the simpliest thing I found

- I try changing minimal sdk target from 14 to 24 but problem continues
- invalited caches and restart (few times)
- check updates
- add compatibility to an especified java sdk 1.6/7/8

build output
https://pastebin.com/Vw9aZ4NX

```
    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/n0n1ck/Proyectos/AndroidStudioProjects/FireFreeDiamonds

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class javax.inject.Inject found in modules jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Named found in modules jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Provider found in modules jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Qualifier found in modules jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Scope found in modules jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Singleton found in modules jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.aop.Advice found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.aop.AspectException found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.ConstructorInterceptor found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.ConstructorInvocation found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.Interceptor found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.Invocation found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation found in modules aopalliance-1.0.jar (aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0) and aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
13 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 6 up-to-date
```

project
https://github.com/g4b0m4n/FireFreeDiamonds

Comment: I forgot my github profile is hide here is the code https://anonfiles.com/jbJdc5F8o8/FireFreeDiamonds-master_zip

Comment: ok I do Build > Clean Project and Build > Rebuild Project but the issue still exist

Comment: I fix the package and rollback telegram API but error continues